# How to validate the content of a user account?

Tags: account

We would like to build a website as a communication platform between Native and Non-Native K-12 students. An example is that Non-Native student can ask questions to Native students and Native students can reply. Another example is that we hope Native students can write blogs or upload images and videos to let people know what is going on in tribes.

We are stuck in designing a website that can work. We have to make sure the text and multimedia from Native students are indeed from Native students. We believe that students need to have accounts at the website. The problem is how to make sure a Native student account is indeed a Native student account. The same goes for Non-Native student accounts. Now matter what the validation approach is, we need to make sure the approach is scalable because there are so many Native and Non-Native students out there.

Comment: A wonderful initiative, however I feel that the question is off-topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I have for this would be you'd need a government ID validation service upon registering. Other than that you can ask for zip or address and validate based on that, but that's not really reliable.